# one source code multiple databases in prestashop 1.7

Tags: apache, prestashop, virtualhost, prestashop-1.7

Requirement : Different eshop/websites to refer one source which is connecting to different databases based on domain

Environment : Cloud Linux , easy apache , php , mysql , cPanel/WHM

Description : We are having two eshops , abc.shop.com(dbname : abc) should connect to database abc and apache should refer common source located at /home/ and def.shop.com(dbname : def) should connect to database def and apache should refer common source located at /home/

In Short both the eshops/websites are having common source code but connecting to different databases

Trial and Analysis : we have virtual host entries in apache , i changed document root location for both the websites and permission also i tried with enabling and disabling cache also ,  but getting error attached

is there any way to achieve one source code and multiple databases for each websites using prestashop 1.7

Answer (score 0):

You can check in config/defines.inc.php what $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] you are targetting and select a database based on this. I don't see any other solution.